# Two related, but independent projects -- Two repositories or one?

Tags: project-management, git

I've made two "complimenting" projects. These two projects are stand alone, but are almost designed to be used together. They are both fairly small projects as well. I'm wanting to host the code on GitHub, but I'm not sure if I should use two repositories or one for this. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Any chance you can tell us what they are so we can determine how they are related?

Comment: @Jeff Well, one is basically a view engine, and the other is an ASP.Net routing framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they are independent, they should be separate repositories. They will likely have different rates of change and you will probably want to create separate releases, etc. You can use git submodules to include one in the other (if appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

If at least one of the projects is usable without the another (and it's not a collection of unittests) then use two. One disadvantage of git is the inability to partially clone repositories. This might not be a problem in the present, but if the project grows big and someone is only interested in one of them, they would have to download the other, too.